# How is registering a pretty printer helpful in GDB

Tags: gdb, pretty-print

I tried registering a pretty printer. It does show up when I write "info pretty-printer" on the gdb command prompt. But how does this help. I have to do everything I did before registering a pretty printer. e.g., Before registering, if I sourced my pretty printer and then called the invoke method with "command-name expr", I still do the same after registering. What value does registering bring to my pretty printer.

Answer (score 0):

If your pretty printer has an associated lookup function, the gdb `print` command can call your pretty printer with no need to explicitly invoke a command provided by your pretty printer. [This page](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html) includes an example which uses the `gdb.printing` module to associate two pretty printers with two regular expressions via `gdb.printing.RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter`. Perhaps you can also find native examples by chasing down the contents of `gdb.pretty_printers`; mine includes a `libstdcxx.v6.printers.Printer` object and a `gdb.printing.RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter` object; the former is defined, on my system, in `/usr/share/gcc-4.8/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py`.

Answer (score 0):

> Before registering, if I sourced my pretty printer and then called the
>   invoke method with "command-name expr", I still do the same after
>   registering.

From this sentence it sounds like you are confusing commands and pretty-printers.  A command implementation has an `invoke` method.  A pretty-printer does not.  Furthermore, a command is invoked from the gdb command line like `(gdb) command-name`, while a pretty-printer is invoked only when a value is being printed, say via `print mumble` (or at other points, like when an argument's value is printed during a backtrace).

Registering your command as if it were a pretty-printer is not useful and will probably just cause the occasional Python exception to be printed.

Comment: Currently if I wrote a python scripts which creates a new command to print a linked list structure. If I want a pretty printer for the same, how should I go about it. Will the structure still look the same or will it be completely different from what I did previously.

Comment: See https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html#Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.  The structure will be somewhat different -- the logic for decoding your data structures will be similar, but interfacing to gdb will differ.  Pretty-printers are generally better than custom commands as they integrate with gdb more nicely.